# Best Design Pattern for Large Data processing methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns, coding-style

I have an application that I am refactoring and trying to Follow some of the "Clean Code" principles. I have an application that reads data from multiple different data sources and manipulates/formats that data and inserts it into another database. I have a data layer with the associated DTO's, repositories, interfaces , and helpers for each data source as well as a business layer with the matching entities, repositories and interfaces.

My question comes down to the Import Method.  I basically have one method that systematically calls each Business logic method to read, process and save the data.  There are a lot of calls that need to be made and even though the Import method itself is not manipulating the data at all, the method is still extremely large.  Is there a better way to process this data?

```
ICustomer<Customer> sourceCustomerList = new CustomerRepository();
foreach (Customer customer in sourceCustomerList.GetAllCustomers())
{

   // Read Some Data
   DataObject object1 = iSourceDataType1.GetDataByCustomerID(customer.ID)
   // Format and save the Data
   iTargetDataType1.InsertDataType1(object1)

   // Read Some Data

   // Format the Data

   // Save the Data

   //...Rinse and repeat
}
```

Comment: I find TPL dataflow good for these kind of things. its immensely powerful and a great fit for pipelines of data that needs to be processed

Comment: Here are some things that i think need to be factored into your question for an appropriate answer. What happens if there is an exception, do you need to rollback everything, or just process from the start again? or pick up where you left off in the process? How much data will be processed? if you are dealing with large amounts of data when reading, the memory footprint of your c# application will increase dramatically.

Comment: on exception I need to stop, figure out why the exception occurred and either fix it in code or in the data itself and pick back up where left of.  So i need to keep track of the iterations and be able specify which iteration to start on.

I am dealing with large amounts of data but only in a bunch of small chuncks at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) and [Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

```
ICustomer<Customer> sourceCustomerList = new CustomerRepository();

var customersBuffer = new BufferBlock<Customer>();
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Customer, DataObject>(
    customer => iSourceDataType1.GetDataByCustomerID(customer.ID)
);

// Build your block with TransformBlock, ActionBlock, many more... 
customersBuffer.LinkTo(transformBlock);

// Add all the blocks you need here....

// Then feed the first block or use a custom source
foreach (var c in sourceCustomerList.GetAllCustomers())
    customersBuffer.Post(c)
customersBuffer.Complete();
```

Comment: This looks like a pretty nice workflow, but how do I continue the for each from a transform block if I need to?

Answer (score 0):

Your performance will be IO-bound, especially with the many accesses to the database(s) in each iteration. Therefore, you need to revise your architecture to minimise IO.

Is it possible to move all the records closer together (maybe in a temporary database) as a first pass, then do the record matching and formatting within the database as a second pass, before reading them out and saving them where they need to be?

(As a side note, sometimes we get carried away with DDD and OO, where everything "needs" to be an object. But that is not always the best approach.)